# Typescript - Overloading private method

Tags: typescript, private, overloading

Hello I would like to achieve this scenario:

```
class A implements InterfaceForA
{
    a():void
    {
        this.b();
    }
}

Class B extends A
{
    private b():void
    {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}
```

But it throws:

> error TS2339: Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'.

So I updated my class and now it throws:

> error TS2415: Class 'B' incorrectly extends base class 'A'. Types have separate declarations of a private property 'b'.

With code:

```
class A implements InterfaceForA
{
    a():void
    {
        this.b();
    }

    private b():void
    {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
}

Class B extends A
{
    private b():void
    {
        console.log('Hi');
    }
}
```

In C++, I would set in class A method b() as virtual private, and problem would be solved. In JS it wouldn't be problem at all. How to do it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 10):

In C++ you would actually set it as protected. Private members are private.

Typescript >= 1.3 supports protected qualifier.

See: [What is the equivalent of protected in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275730/what-is-the-equivalent-of-protected-in-typescript)

Comment: In C++, 'private virtual' differs from protected. It can be overridden, but cannot be called from derived class.

Comment: @AntonPilyak Thanks! Good to know.